# Run node script in cron job

Tags: node.js, cron

I am trying to run a node script with cron every minute. I dont believe it is running at all. When I run `grep cron /var/log/syslog` I dont see it running in the log.

Did I write the cron job wrong? If so how do I run a node script in a cron job?

```
 * * * * * node /home/ubuntu/Server/nodeScript.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron jobs don't run in a shell so you have to give the full path to the node binary.

`/usr/bin/node`  (or whatever it is on that machine)

Try `which node` to find out

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run it every single minute is just to put your code in endless loop with timeout.

For example

```
function yourCode () {
    for {
        // your code
        timeout(60 * 1000)
    }
}
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Just be sure you run it with `pm2` or `supervisor` so when it crashes it can restart automatically.